# Error: There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I followed the documentation for adding a custom route. When I click on the button in the list view, I get the error:

> There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `***\UserController` and the current route `resetPassword`

The docs: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/routing.html

My Admin Service is defined as follows:

```
sonata.admin.user:
    class: ****\Admin\UserAdmin #User Admin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, model_manager: cems_model_manager, manager_type: orm, group: core, label: "Users" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - models\User #User Model
        - '****Bundle:User' #User Controller
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [****Bundle]]
```

I have added my route in my UserAdmin

```
  protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
  {
      parent::configureRoutes($collection);
      $collection->add('password_reset', $this->getRouterIdParameter() . '/resetPassword/');
  }
```

And created the custom controller and action.

```
  <?php

  namespace ****\Controller;

  use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  class UserController extends CRUDController
  {

      /**
       * @Route("/User/{userId}/resetPassword/", name="resetPassword")
       */
      public function resetPasswordAction(Request $request, $userId)
      {
          // code here 
      } 
  }
```

The route works fine if I browse to it manually or via an ajax call, which our application does at another point.  But when I try to click on the button in the list view, which is generated in the configureListFields() in UserAdmin, I get the subject error. I can't figure out how any of the other default actions put the code into the request, they look the same as this one does. I found a few other people asking this question when I googled the error but my admin appears to be configured correctly, and that was the only answer I could find - and it seems outdated as the arguments appear to be in different orders now.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: I had not this situation but still same error, and for me helped passing to route parameter: $this->router->generate('statements', ['_sonata_admin' => 'vop_policy.policy_admin'])

Answer (score 3):

Its only idea, not tested - maybe you must have controller action coresponding with route name (not with pattern string): 
password_reset -> passwordResetAction

Comment: Yep, solution had to do with changing route name and settings. 

I figured it out with some help on Sonata Devs google group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonata-devs/8GK0kpa2cik/5UCE_eLMixoJ

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `@Route("/User/{userId}/resetPassword/", name="resetPassword")`
since its defined before in configureRoutes function.