# Sonata admin dynamically change input data based on selected value - custom controller

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to implement dynamics inputs into a Sonata form. 
When an user choose a category, I'd like to change an other list of values.

So I created a new Controller, I configure a new route and I created a new twig model.

For now, I have this :

```php
class MyController extends CRUDController
{
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $transitRepository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Transit");

        $transits = $transitRepository->findTransitWithType($request->query->get("type"));
        return $this->render("transits.html.twig", array("transits" => $transits));       
    }
```

My twig model :

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block itineraire_widget %}


<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_start(form, { 'id': id } ) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}    

              {{ form_label (form.type, "Type") }}
              {{ form_widget(form.type, {'attr' : {'class' : 'typeclass-' ~ id ~ ' span3'}}) }}
              {{ form_errors(form.type) }}

              {{ form_label (form.transit, "Transit") }}
              {{ form_widget(form.transit, {'attr' : {'class' : 'transitclass-' ~ id ~ ' span3'}}) }}
              {{ form_errors(form.transit) }}


        {{ form_end(form) }} 
</div>

    {% block javascripts %}

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".typeclass-{{id}}").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('transit_list') }}",
                data: {
                    'type': $(this).val()
                },
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (html) {
                    var transitSelector = $(".transitclass-{{id}}");
                    transitSelector.empty();

                    transitSelector.append(html);
                 },
                error: function (data) {
                     console.log("An error ocurred while loading data ...");
                }
            });
        });
    });
        </script>

    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

I added the service to the service.yml file :

```
    app.admin.transit.mouv:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\Transit_mouvAdmin
        arguments: 
            - ~
            - AppBundle\Entity\Transit_mouv
            - AppBundle\Controller\MyController
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Transit_mouv }
```

And then I added the route to the route.yml :

```
transit_list:
    resource: 
    path:     /get-transits-from-type
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:TransitMouv:listTransitByType" }
    methods:  GET
```

But I have a problem with Sonata, when I want to load the list, depend of the type attribute, I have an error :

> There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `AppBundle\Controller\TransitMouvController` and the current route `transit_list`

I probably miss something with Sonata admin..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This may help, looks like it could be a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288729/error-there-is-no-sonata-admin-defined-for-the-controller

Comment: I saw this question, but I didn't find the solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to add a configureRoute function in my admin class (instead of configure route in the routing.yml file) :

```php
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        parent::configureRoutes($collection);
        $collection->add('transit_list',  'transitList');
    }
```

Then, in my twig model, I tried :

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ admin.generateUrl('transitList') }}",
                data: {
                    'type': $(this).val()
                },
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (html) {
                    //code
                 },
                error: function (data) {
                     console.log("An error ocurred while loading data ...");
                }
            });
```

In this case, I have this error :

> Variable "admin" does not exist.

I follow this post: 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/3458763](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587631/symfony2-sonata-admin-dynamically-change-input-data-based-on-selected-value/34588203)